# Sybase Database : least permission/roles to extract ddl

Tags: permissions, ddl, role, sybase-central

I am currently using Sybase Central 15.x. In which I have a database, a login and a User.
Here I need to give permission(s)/role(s) to a user by which it able to extract ddl of database.
There I found that if I give sa_role then user can extract ddl. But as I know sa_role make a user as a super user(sa). So I need to know that there exist any other permission/role to do the same task.

Comment: What DDL is the user trying to extract, and what tool are they using to extract the DDL?

Comment: "A database script which includes all objects" is my "DDL" and we are using "ddlgen" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ASE Utility Guide; Section: ddlgen](https://help.sap.com/viewer/da6c1d172bef4597a78dc5e81a9bb947/16.0.3.0/en-US/a7ed349ebc2b1014b50fbd20d6921128.html), regarding **Permissions** required to use `ddlgen`:

```
Users must have either sa_role or sso_role to generate DDL for:
- Encryption keys
- Logins
- Roles
For all other objects, users do not need any specific permissions or roles to generate DDL
```

Is your user receiving errors when they attempt to use `ddlgen` (and if so, what errors)?